# Why is the Intellisense for properties and methods of instantiated datacontext not showing?

Tags: linq, datacontext

I have a web application project within VS 2008 and I have created a Linq to SQL file onto which I have dragged a table from my data base. The data context is created fine but when I instantiate an object of this type the only item I get showing on the Intellisense for it is the class based on the table I dragged onto the designer and even on this I get no Intellisense if I put a dot after it. Has anyone any idea why I am not seeing all the methods for this datacontext (i.e. SubmitChanges etc).

```
EmsContentModelDataContext context;

#region Methods

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    context = new EmsContentModelDataContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

OK - it turns out relatively simple. It was just that there were compile errors within that class that was causing the intellisense to break. When I recreated the file from new and cleared the compile errors I got the intellisense back.